# Absolute URLs in Web.siteMap

Tags: asp.net

In a website project (VS 2010) I do have a `<asp:Menu>` that feeds on the web.sitemap using the `System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider` having security trimming enabled.

All works well. Obviously a user has to authenticate as "Administrator" to see the child nodes from the sample below. But the issue here is that **sitemap nodes with absolute urls do not show in the menu**.  Below is an excerpt of the web.sitemap:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Administration/default.aspx" title="Administration" roles="Administrator" >
   <siteMapNode url="~/Administration/worksfine.aspx" title="Does show" />
   <siteMapNode url="http://pmspublic.in.ohchr.org" title="Does not show" />
</siteMapNode>
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this without hacking into the DataBound Event of the menu control?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is security trimming enabled and the node with the absolute url was inside a restricted SiteMapNode. Since the external URL does not have a web.config to check current user's permissions the respective sitemap node was simply dropped.

**Solution:** Add a `roles="*"` to the absolute url node and the security trimming for that node will be skipped since everybody is allowed to access the node anyway. Like this:

```
<siteMapNode url="~/Administration/default.aspx" title="Administration" roles="Administrator" >
   <siteMapNode url="~/Administration/worksfine.aspx" title="Does show" />
   <siteMapNode url="http://pmspublic.in.ohchr.org" title="Does not show" roles="*" />
</siteMapNode>
```